# Swift. how to modify navigation stack to display another view controller in a queue

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigation stack where I have next view controllers

```
navigation controller -> dashboard view controller -> settings view controller
```

On setting screen I want to change some settings and when I go back I need to display other view controller. The navigation stack will looks like this

```
navigation controller -> maintenance view controller
```

How to do it in a right way, the one way I think about replace navigation stack. But maybe there is some better solution with composition.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I will pop to root, then push new controller

So in setting view controller, after saved new setting you can try as bellow

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

let maintenanceVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MaintenanceId")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(maintenanceVC!, animated: false)
```

Make sure use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` with animated to `true`